# "Duplicate resources" when running official tutorial

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I'm performing the steps in an Android tutorial here: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html

When I do the step to "Run on an Emulator" (running on the emulator), I get an error.
I have double checked all the steps, but can't see what is wrong.
Can anyone help?

Here is the compile output:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:assembleDebug]
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> [string/app_name] C:\Users\eddyq\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\src\main\res\values\strings.xml  [string/app_name] C:\Users\eddyq\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\src\main\res\values\styles.xml: Error: Duplicate resources
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 17.608 secs
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Here is the build.gradle for the project:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Here is the build.gradle for the app:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Here is styles.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">My Application</string>
    <string name="edit_message">Enter a message</string>
    <string name="button_send">Send</string>
</resources>
```

Here is strings.xml:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">My Application</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: Can you post your `build.gradle` ?

Comment: Sure, but you can edit your own question. Adding your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Here is styles.xml:
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <resources>
>     <string name="app_name">My Application</string>
>     <string name="edit_message">Enter a message</string>
>     <string name="button_send">Send</string>
> </resources>
> ```

This isn't what should be in your `styles.xml`. Those are strings anyways, not styles.

Plus, the error clearly says the `"app_name"` string is duplicated. (Emphasis added)

> [**string/app_name**] ..\app\src\main\res\values\ **strings.xml**
>     [**string/app_name**] ..\app\src\main\res\values\ **styles.xml**
>   Error: Duplicate resources

If you make a brand new project in Android Studio, you should not need to change anything in the `styles.xml` files.

And [I can't find where it says to modify `styles.xml` anywhere](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html#Strings).

---

For reference, the `styles.xml` should look similar to this

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/PrimaryColor</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/PrimaryDarkColor</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>
    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
</resources>
```

Comment: Thanks. yes, I clearly saw the "app_name" mentioned as duplicated. And I don't see any mention of styles.xml in the tutorial so I think it must be automatically generated. I will study the tutorial more in an hour or so.

Comment: The file is automatically generated, yes. I've added what the `styles.xml` should look like (in case you did replace the entire content with the `string` resources)

Comment: I think when the tutorial said to click strings.xml I inadvertently clicked styles.xml. I fixed it, thanks.